# How to move emails with same subject of one selected email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to move emails from one folder to another based on the selection of one item.

If I choose one email I want all email with a similar subject to be moved from that folder into another folder (we can sort by subject and move the email, this may be faster).

Also I want to calculate response time of first received email with same subject and the response time of the email which I have replied at the last.

Moving one email is working.

Example
Subject of the email: Need data
Received at 1 AM, acknowledged at 1:10 AM and responded at 1:40 AM
In that case I need to calculate the timings as 40 MIN

Answer (score 0):

> i have tried selecting one email and run the macro and it is moving to another folder correctly but i need all the similar subject of the has to be moved faster

To find items that correspond to your conditions in Outlook you may use the following methods:

1. [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) - read more about these methods in the [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/) article.
2. [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) - read more about this method in the [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) article.
3. [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) - see [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.

The [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) method can be used for moving items into another folder.